# Spacing on x-axis using ggplot2 discrete scale

Tags: r, ggplot2, discrete

I've been working with this code for a while but this is the first time I've only had two categories on my x-axis. For some reason, R will not space out the bins and instead bunches them at the beginning. How do I evenly spread them along the x-axis?

```
xlabels<-c("A","B")
CTplot <- ggplot(CTsum, aes(x=Treatment, y=FI)) + 
  geom_col(fill="lightsteelblue") + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels= xlabels)+xlab("")+ylab("")+
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),axis.text.x = element_text(size=20,color="black"), axis.text.y = element_text(size=20, color="black"), axis.title.x = element_text(size=25), axis.title.y = element_text(size=25))+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = FI - meanse, ymax = FI + meanse, width=0.2))+
  annotate("text",x=1,y=0.84, label="A",size=5)+ 
  annotate("text",x=2,y=0.62, label="B",size=5)+ 
  annotate("text",x=3,y=0.29, label="",size=5)+ 
  annotate("text",x=4,y=0.26, label="",size=5)+
  annotate("text",x=0.65,y=0.5, label="",size=15)
CTplot
```

[image]

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862) on making a reproducible example that is easier for folks to help with. It's hard to know what's wrong without being able to run your code or knowing anything about the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you plot categorical data on the x axis, you are "really" plotting at integer values x = 1, x = 2, etc, but with the text labels used in place of numbers. This is what allows you to put text annotations at x = 1 and x = 2.

However, the bars are bunched at the left because you have added two empty text annotations over to the right (at position x = 3 and x = 4). The plot has expanded right to accommodate them. Since they are empty anyway, you don't need them. Here is the plot without them:

```r
CTplot <- ggplot(CTsum, aes(Treatment, FI)) + 
  geom_col(fill = "lightsteelblue") + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = FI - meanse, ymax = FI + meanse, width = 0.2)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = xlabels) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("") +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=20,color="black"), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=20, color="black"), 
        axis.title.x = element_text(size=25), 
        axis.title.y = element_text(size=25))+
  annotate("text",x=1,y=0.84,label="A",size = 5) +
  annotate("text",x=2,y=0.62,label="B",size = 5)

CTplot
```

[image]

And here it is with an empty annotation at x = 4:

```
CTplot + annotate("text",x = 4, y = 0.29, label = "", size = 5)
```

[image]

To emphasise the point, let's see an empty annotation at x = 20:

```r
CTplot + annotate("text",x = 20, y = 0.29, label = "", size = 5)
```

[image]

As you can see, the x axis has had to expand to accommodate the invisible text annotation at x = 20.

---

If you want the bars a bit more spread out, you can do something like:

```r
CTplot <- ggplot(CTsum, aes(Treatment, FI)) + 
  geom_col(fill = "lightsteelblue", width = 0.6) + 
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = FI - meanse, ymax = FI + meanse, width = 0.2)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = xlabels, expand = c(0.75, 0)) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("") +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=20,color="black"), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=20, color="black"), 
        axis.title.x = element_text(size=25), 
        axis.title.y = element_text(size=25))+
  annotate("text",x=1,y=0.84,label="A",size = 5) +
  annotate("text",x=2,y=0.62,label="B",size = 5)

CTplot
```

[image]

---

**Data used (approximated from image in OP)**

```r
CTsum <- data.frame(Treatment = c("A", "B"), FI = c(0.71, 0.48), meanse = 0.1)
```